# Create a new version of item, in different language

Tags: multilingual

This should be super simple but for some reason I can't get it to work.
I am writing code for migrating data and the items has several versions in both English and Swedish. For some reason I cannot get Sitecore to create a version in English. I'm obviously doing something wrong. I'm not able to track down what is causing it?

the `migratedItem` is the item I just migrated in Swedish and that I want to add a English version too.

```
Item englishItemVersion;
try
{
   using (new LanguageSwitcher("en"))
   {
      englishItemVersion = migratedItem.Versions.AddVersion();                    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, I can see that you are trying to add a new version of the item in the *context* language, as opposed to the language of the actual item. Remember that each instance of a Sitecore item is actually only a single language version of the item. Don't believe me? Have a look at your `item.ItemUri` and see for yourself!

In order to add a new language version to an item, the first thing that you need to do is get the item in the language that you wish to add a new version for. As such, if your code had been the following, it would have worked:

```
using (new LanguageSwitcher("en"))
{
   var migratedItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(migratedItemId);
   englishItemVersion = migratedItem.Versions.AddVersion();                    
}
```

Of course, you can still do the above without a Switcher, if you want to:

```
var migratedItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(migratedItemId, "en");
englishItemVersion = migratedItem.Versions.AddVersion();
```

Comment: This did the trick. Please note that the content editor has some sort of caching that can cause these kind of changes not to show up. That cost a couple of wasted hours before i figured out that the code was actually working, but i could not see the changes in content editor...

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```c#
// get the item in en language - you should get the item but versions count should be 0
Item enItem = migratedItem.Database.GetItem(migratedItem.ID, enLanguage);

// edit the item and create a version
enItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
enItem.Versions.AddVersion();
enItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: Great answer! Just to clarify though, you don't need to `BeginEdit`/`EndEdit` unless you plan to edit fields on the item, as well.